# How Auth0 know if I am already logged in?

Tags: auth0, auth0-js

I'm learning about Auth0. I can't figure out how the Auth0 JS sdk's sliently log the users
for Single Page Application? They said tokens are save in memory, which means they don't know who am I when I next time open my browser, isn't it?

In below official document they say:

*If the user was already logged in to Auth0 and no other interactive prompts are required, Auth0 will respond exactly as if the user had authenticated manually through the login page*

https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/configure-silent-authentication#successful-authentication-responses

My questions are:

1. How they know my email address? (If SDK saves our token in memory)
2. How they know I am already logged in? (Do they check their DB)

Comment: Where does it say that "tokens are save in memory"? Include a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After logging in Auth0 stores your session in a cookie so it is able to keep verifying if you are still logged in and also check if the cookie is still valid.

Comment: Thank you, this is looks like an answer. But, I am still not sure how they know my account/email? When I reopen browser, I see only this cookie -> auth0.<clientID>x2NaN.is.authenticated=true

Comment: I mean this cookie: auth0.<clientID>.is.authenticated=true

Comment: The id set on cookie translates who is logged in based on the cookie management made on Auth0 server.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser has valid session = Auth0 cookie. That cookie is sent with that authentication request and it will be used to (re)identify you.

Comment: Thank  you Jan. I am still not sure how they know my account/email? When I reopen browser, I see only this cookie -> auth0.<clientID>.is.authenticated=true

Comment: @AntonIva it is cookie on Auth0 domain, not on your app domain. Cookie has  "id" which is paired with your user details on Auth0 server.